# how to use prefix in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with laravel 5.2. and I have following route in routes.php

```
Route::prefix('manage')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'ManageController@index');
    Route::get('/dashboard','ManageController@dashboard')->name('manage.dashboard');

});
```

then when I try to php artisan serve command my cmd occured following error

```
Method prefix does not exit
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Try `Route::group(['prefix' => 'manage'], function () { ....` [from docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-prefixes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'manage'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'ManageController@index');
    Route::get('/dashboard','ManageController@dashboard')->name('manage.dashboard');
});
```